# Wolfram Mathematica NDSolve error

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm getting an error for the BC in this equation:

```
s = NDSolve[{D[h[t, x], t] + Sin[x Degree] h[t, x]^2 D[h[t, x], x] + 
     2/3 Cos[x Degree] h[t, x]^3 == 0, h[0, x] == 1, 
   D[h[t, 0], x] == 0}, h, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 90}]
```

> NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {2/3 Cos[[Degree] x] h[t,x]^3+h[t,x]^2 Sin[[Degree] x] (h^(0,1))[t,x]+(h^(1,0))[t,x]==0,h[0,x]==1,True}. >>

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The last condition:

```
D[h[t, 0], x] == 0
```

is always True as you derivate on a constant.  If what you mean is

```
D[ h[t,x], x]  /. x->0
```

that's something else.

For the time being, just remove it (and possibly find another sensible boundary condition compatible with the order of your equation).

```
NDSolve[{D[h[t, x], t] + Sin[x] h[t, x]^2 D[h[t, x], x] + 2/3 Cos[x] h[t, x]^3 == 0, h[0, x] == 1}, h, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, Pi/2}]
```

works with a few warnings about the underdetermined system.

Comment: ogerard, you may not be aware that there is a dedicated [Mathematica.SE] Stack Exchange site.  I hope to see you there.

Comment: Dear @Mr.Wizard, I know, I even was among the committers in Area51. But I like to answer stray Mathematica questions on StackOverflow from time to time as there are so many very knowledgeable Mathematica experts on the Mathematica Stack Exchange Site.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remember seeing you there.  Carry on.